# Why the title I am writing for the post is not showing but another title is showing?

Tags: asynchronous-messaging-protocol

I am writing The Coromandel Fishers :Detailed & Ultimate Guide as the title of my post , but "The Coromandel Fishers :Detailed &Ultimate Guide "

Why amp: is showing on the screen as the title whereas I am writing The Coromandel Fishers :Detailed & Ultimate Guide as the title of my post ?